# Datatables refresh button and spin awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, datatables

I'm using datatables and Font Awesome 4.4.0 and I would like to create a refresh button. So I create this

```
<!-- Main content -->
<section class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Fleets</h3>
                    <span style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-refresh pull-right" aria-hidden="true" id="refreshButton"></i></span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-header -->
                <div class="box-body">
                    <!--  Fleets table -->
                    <table id="fleetsTable"
                        class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Applications</th>
                                <th>Fleet name</th>
                                <th>Creation date</th>
                                <th>Statistic</th>
                                <th>Edit</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
    ....
```

and in javascript I have(as @Dekel suggested)

```
 $('#refreshButton').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
   var el = $(this);
   fleetTable.ajax.reload(function() {
       el.removeClass('fa-spin');
   });
});
```

If I use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhwfnh61/) it works fine but in my page it doesn't work, the spin tag is ignored, so the icon is static.
In this page I use angularJs, may be this the problem (I tried also with only html code, with spin even added but it doesn't work yet)?
My first step was test only HTML code:

```
<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
```

and it didn't work.
So here:
[image]
I import font-awesome.min.css
Many thanks
[image]
***RESOLVED***: I have updated my awesome css with the new version and it works. The code provided by @Dekel has helped me to remove spin after table refresh.

Comment: Even adding the `fa-spin` manually it doesn't work?

Comment: it doesn't work even with <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i> like awesome example page

Comment: In which browser are you testing it?

Comment: .Is the Font Awesome script loaded? If it is not working even for static fa classes, then it's got nothing to do with your Angular/jQuery code

Comment: And if you are using angularjs, then you shouldn't be using jquery events for click funtions and classes. try using ng-click and ng-class.

Comment: I used ng-click and it didn't word so I tried with jquery.  Is there a .js for awesome? I have only font-awesome.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the call to `fleetTable.ajax.reload()` returns immediately, so your code actually does `$(this).addClass('fa-spin')` and immediately after it you have `$(this).removeClass('fa-spin')` (so you get no animation).

Instead - what you can do is use the `callback` of the ajax function:

```
$('#refreshButton').click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('fa-spin');
   var el = $(this);
   fleetTable.ajax.reload(function() {
       el.removeClass('fa-spin');
   });
});
```

This way the `fa-spin` class will be removed from your element only **after** the ajax call is done.

Comment: Yes I know this problem indeed I removed ajax reload but it didn't work. It odd that even static html spin doesn't work.

Comment: You have anticipated something I had to see later. I updated with further details

Comment: Ok, let me know after you update the question with new details.

Comment: I updated the question, the problem is the spin tag that doesn't animate the icon

Comment: Can you provide a working example (with the datatable and everything?) Do you see that the datatable actually get refreshed?

Comment: yes but the problem is the fa-spin, even without javascript and datatables it doesn't work

Comment: I think you have some problem with your code. This `fa-spin` works perfectly: http://jsfiddle.net/wtdtn38h/

Comment: yes, but why? I added the picture of chrome debug, the code seems fine.

Comment: As already mentioned - without actual working example (that demonstrates a code that **should** work but **doesn't** work) it's not possible to help.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of "late-to-the-game" answer but to clarify on Dekel's answer above, you need to make sure you define fleetTable like so:

```
 var fleetTable = $('#id to your table').DataTable();
```

This is working for me without adding anything to the dataTables initialization. The whole code in my application below is called after the table code:

```
$('<button id="refreshButton" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-fw"></i></button>').prependTo('div.dataTables_filter');

$('#refreshButton').click(function(){
   var table = $('#grid-data').DataTable();
   $(this).children().addClass('fa-spin');
   var el = $(this);
   table.ajax.reload(function() {
       el.children().removeClass('fa-spin');
   });
});
```

You can `prependTo` or `appendTo` depending on your taste.